# Do high turnouts help more liberal politicians?

Tags: united-states, voter-turnout

People often say that Donald Trump won the US election because the [turnout was low](http://www.salon.com/2017/05/14/how-unequal-voter-turnout-and-vote-suppression-helped-elect-donald-trump/), and that the Tories' victory in June will depend on a [potentially low](http://www.newstatesman.com/politics/elections/2017/04/four-thoughts-theresa-mays-general-election-decision) turnout.

However, is it actually true that a high turnout always helps the liberal candidate?

Comment: There is always an excuse for losing for any side so long as it isn't the party's fault. In short this excuse so far as I see it is, "If I had more voters I would have won". Not too helpful just a comment

Comment: You may also want to note that the last time turnout was this low was also the last time the popular vote winner lost, when Gore won the popular vote but Bush won the Electoral College.

Comment: Please limit this question to a jurisdiction.

Comment: @KDog can I ask about UK+US?

Comment: Sure, see my edits in the title too to see if you agree

Comment: This question deserves more research. I just discovered that Democrats prefer to keep downballot issues to off-years, which is another form of voter suppression, as voters clearly prefer to vote on all issues at once during "election" years, which sort of contradicts the notion that higher turnout benefits liberals. https://fivethirtyeight.com/features/how-democrats-suppress-the-vote/

Comment: Also, the edited title is a much different question than what the questioner asked. The standard is absurdly lower. Anyone can find evidence for every which way and that would be good enough to answer the edited question, but that wasn't the original question. The original question had a much higher standard, "Has it been *proven* to help liberals?"

Comment: @JDoe post reverted

Comment: Solely based on the US, trends are that demographic groups that tend to vote liberal are growing and those that tend to vote conservative are shrinking. The battle then becomes between those two demographics. You obviously want your own party's demographic to come out in numbers.

Comment: This is a more complicated question than it seems on the surface. There is a core of people that will vote no matter what, but for others getting to the polls (transportation, work schedule, etc) can be more difficult. Those that are poor, minority, elderly, college-aged, fall disproportionately into this category, and those groups vote disproportionately democratic. So some kinds of efforts to widen voter participation (early voting, voting by mail) will help these groups more than "core voters", so Republicans generally oppose these efforts. But its more than just a raw "turnout" number.

Comment: Since you've referenced the UK elections, and the Liberal Democrats are a well known party there, is there any chance of replacing "liberal" with something less ambiguous?

Comment: @origimbo I would say "non-establishment" but hardly anyone would say Hillary Clinton is one.

Comment: Based on the following PhD thesis, maybe something like "party with more traditional support from those of lower socioeconomic status"? https://dash.harvard.edu/bitstream/handle/1/11156810/Fowler_gsas.harvard_0084L_10773.pdf?sequence=1

Comment: @origimbo aren't the Tories more popular with the poor?

Comment: https://www.ipsos.com/ipsos-mori/en-uk/how-britain-voted-2015

Comment: turnout wasn't low in the 2016 us election.

Comment: For US, the fact that [youth is more liberal](http://nymag.com/daily/intelligencer/2018/03/new-survey-young-staying-liberal-conservatives-dying-off.html) and also [has the lowest turnover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Youth_vote_in_the_United_States) might be part of the explanation.

Comment: The analysis is likely quite different in the U.K. than in the U.S. because the electoral mechanics are so different.